# Open text file and replace line that contains specific words

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to replace specific lines of text, example

```
myvalue1 = "cat"
myvalue2 = "mouse"
```

So if I wanted to change the value of `myvalue1` to dog, as an example.  The text file will have many lines as they will be javascript variable, so I am trying to find a way to open text file and update certain variables.  Thanks in advance

Comment: try RegEx. It is used exactly for that purpose.

Comment: you may need a specific example of how you plan to implement this. i'm following you "in general", but an "in general" answer isn't probably going to help you.

Comment: hurm that looks like it should be in a database

Comment: I like the idea of placing variable into database, maybe I will think about that, thanks